# LINQ Query to remove duplicate items in a List based on the value

Tags: c#, list, linq

I have a list containing 600+ objects in this form:

Each object has an `ItemCode` property and an `ItemCost` property

I'm trying to write a C# Language Integrated Query (LINQ) to

1. Find items in this list with the same ItemCode.
2. And delete the one with the higher ItemCost.

For example, if there are 2 items in this list with the same ItemCode = RNWA.

If one of them has an ItemCost of 4.65 and the other has an ItemCost of 3

I would like to delete the one with the higher ItemCost of 4.65

My first approach is to find/select items with the ItemCodes occurring more than once.

Here are some of my "unsuccessful" attempts (`where dataSet is the list of objects`)

1. `dataSet.Select(x => x.ItemCode).Where(x => x.Count() > 1).Cast<Dictionary<string, decimal>>();`
2. `dataSet.GroupBy(x => x).Where(g => g.Count() > 1).Select(g => g).ToList().Cast<Dictionary<string, decimal>>()`
3. `dataSet.GroupBy(x => x.ItemCode).Where(x => x.Count() > 1).Cast<Dictionary<string, decimal>>();`

Please can anyone point me in the direction. Thank you!

Comment: A dictionary cannot contain entries with the same Key (ItemCode).

Comment: Sorry i explained wrong, its actually a list of objects. I'll edit my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With combination of `GroupBy` and `.ToDictionary` you can build a dictionary with `ItemCode` as a key and lowest `ItemCost` as a value.

```
var result = dataSet
    .GroupBy(i => i.ItemCode)
    .ToDictionary(group => group.Key, group => group.Min(i => i.ItemCost));
```

Comment: This is exactly what I've been trying to achieve and it worked. Thank you so much Fabio! Appreciate it!